# Why i can't see a change in the status of the database MySQL when i do this update?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mysql-workbench, e-commerce

I'm trying to implement an e-commerce website using java, MySQL database, and JDBC.

I have a problem when I (intentionally) cause an OptimisticLockException or a NotAvaibleProductException: in these exceptions(inside the catch) i try to delete an order with a given ID with the function orderDAO.permanentlydelete(order);

I haven't got any error and every transactions that there are in the program changed the database status as i wanted, **except for the DELETE performed inside the function** **orderDAO.permanentlydelete(order);**

In fact in MySQL WorkBench **continue to be present the order with the ID that i wanted to delete.**

This is the **controller function:**

```
public static void addPaymentAndOrderChange(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String applicationMessage = null;
    DAOFactory sessionDAOFactory = null;
    DAOFactory daoFactory = null;
    Utente loggedUser;


    Logger logger = LogService.getApplicationLogger();

    try {

        Map sessionFactoryParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        sessionFactoryParameters.put("request", request);
        sessionFactoryParameters.put("response", response);
        sessionDAOFactory = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(Configuration.COOKIE_IMPL, sessionFactoryParameters);
        sessionDAOFactory.beginTransaction();

        UserDAO sessionUserDAO = sessionDAOFactory.getUserDAO();
        loggedUser = sessionUserDAO.findLoggedUser();

        daoFactory = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory(Configuration.DAO_IMPL, null);
        daoFactory.beginTransaction();

        Double CardNumber= Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("CardNumber"));
        int CVV = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cvv"));
        String name= request.getParameter("name");
        String expiration= request.getParameter("expiration");



        /* I find the pending order linked with logged user*/
        OrderDAO orderDAO = daoFactory.getOrderDAO();
        Order order = orderDAO.findByPendingStatus(loggedUser);

        //I find the cart
        CartDAO cartDAO = daoFactory.getCartDAO();
        Cart cart = cartDAO.findCartByOrder(order);

        //Take all the cart item inside the cart
        CartItemDAO cartItemDAO = daoFactory.getCartItemDAO();
        List<CartItem> cartItems = cartItemDAO.getCartItems(cart);


     try {
            //I create the payment
            PaymentDAO paymentDAO = daoFactory.getPaymentDAO();
            paymentDAO.create(cart.getTotal(), order, CardNumber, CVV, name, expiration);

            //Set complete flag to the order
            orderDAO.setCompleteStatus(order);
            System.out.println(order.getID_order());


            //Decrease the quantity of the product
            for (CartItem cartItem : cartItems) {
                ProductDAO productDAO = daoFactory.getProductDAO();
                productDAO.checkAndDecreaseQuantity(cartItem.getProduct().getId_product(), cartItem.getQuantity());

            }


            //Prepare data for the next jsp page
            Map<CartItem, Product> cartItems_page;
            cartItems_page = cartItemDAO.findOrderItems(order.getID_order());


            daoFactory.commitTransaction();
            sessionDAOFactory.commitTransaction();

            applicationMessage = "Payment received, order executed successfully";
            System.out.println(applicationMessage);


            request.setAttribute("loggedOn", loggedUser != null);
            request.setAttribute("ID_order", order.getID_ordine());
            request.setAttribute("CartItems", cartItems_page);
            request.setAttribute("loggedUser", loggedUser);
            request.setAttribute("applicationMessage", applicationMessage);

            request.setAttribute("viewUrl", "jsp/userOrderManagement/Order_details");


        } catch (NotAvaibleProductException e) {
            try {
                if (daoFactory != null) daoFactory.rollbackTransaction();

            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
            applicationMessage="NotAvaibleProductException : Reorder";
            daoFactory.beginTransaction();

              ** //I cancel the order
            orderDAO.permanentlydelete(order); **


            //I delete the previous created cart
            CartDAO cartDAO = daoFactory.getCartDAO();
            Cart Opencart = cartDAO.findOpenCartByUserId(loggedUser.getId_user());
            cartDAO.delete(Opencart);

            //i open the cart that have been closed
            cartDAO.restoreCart(cart);

            //I send the user into the cart.jsp page
            commonView(daoFactory,sessionDAOFactory,request);


            daoFactory.commitTransaction();
            sessionDAOFactory.commitTransaction();


            request.setAttribute("loggedOn", loggedUser != null);
            request.setAttribute("loggedUser", loggedUser);
            request.setAttribute("viewUrl", "jsp/cartManagement/Cart");
            request.setAttribute("applicationMessage", applicationMessage);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Controller Error", e);
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION");
        try {
            if (daoFactory != null) daoFactory.rollbackTransaction();
            if (sessionDAOFactory != null) sessionDAOFactory.rollbackTransaction();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(e);


    } finally {
        try {
            if (daoFactory != null) daoFactory.closeTransaction();
            if (sessionDAOFactory != null) sessionDAOFactory.closeTransaction();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
    }
```

And this is the **function that perform the delete**:

```
  public void permanentlydelete(Order order){
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {

        String sql
                = " DELETE FROM ORDINE "
                + " WHERE "
                + " ID_ordine=?";

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setLong(1, order.getID_order());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**And this is the general log:**

2023-08-23T17:45:17.262776Z    26 Connect   root@localhost on amuletshop using TCP/IP

2023-08-23T17:45:17.263529Z    26 Query /* mysql-connector-j-8.0.32 (Revision: fa4912a849140828e48162a2c396c8df0091bed7) */SELECT  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment, @@character_set_client AS character_set_client, @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection, @@character_set_results AS character_set_results, @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@collation_server AS collation_server, @@collation_connection AS collation_connection, @@init_connect AS init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@license AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names, @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout, @@performance_schema AS performance_schema, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@transaction_isolation AS transaction_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout

```
2023-08-23T17:45:17.264237Z    26 Query SET character_set_results = NULL

2023-08-23T17:45:17.264693Z    26 Query SET autocommit=1

2023-08-23T17:45:17.265188Z    26 Query SET autocommit=0

2023-08-23T17:45:17.265919Z    26 Query SELECT *    FROM ORDINE  WHERE    Stato_o = 'In sospeso' AND ID_utente=31 AND Deleted=0 ORDER BY ID_ordine DESC LIMIT 1

2023-08-23T17:45:17.270339Z    26 Query SELECT * FROM ORDINE JOIN CARRELLO ON ID_cart=ID_carrello  WHERE  (ID_ordine=125)

2023-08-23T17:45:17.272270Z    26 Query SELECT *  FROM CARTITEM  WHERE    ID_car = 141    AND deleted = 'N'

2023-08-23T17:45:17.274521Z    26 Query SELECT *  FROM PAGAMENTO  WHERE  Deleted ='N' AND ID_order=125

2023-08-23T17:45:17.276718Z    26 Query INSERT INTO PAGAMENTO    ( Importo,     ID_order,     NumeroCarta,     CVV,     Nome,     ScadenzaCarta   )  VALUES (300000.00,125,2.0,1,'Ydfuf','1')

2023-08-23T17:45:17.278111Z    26 Query UPDATE ORDINE  SET Stato_o='Completato'  WHERE  ID_ordine=125

2023-08-23T17:45:17.279899Z    26 Query SELECT * FROM PRODOTTO  WHERE    Deleted=0 AND Blocked=0 AND ID_amuleto=11 AND Quantità_disp>=3

2023-08-23T17:45:17.280947Z    26 Query rollback


2023-08-23T17:45:17.286115Z    27 Connect   root@localhost on amuletshop using TCP/IP
```

2023-08-23T17:45:17.286988Z    27 Query /* mysql-connector-j-8.0.32 (Revision: fa4912a849140828e48162a2c396c8df0091bed7) */SELECT  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment, @@character_set_client AS character_set_client, @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection, @@character_set_results AS character_set_results, @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@collation_server AS collation_server, @@collation_connection AS collation_connection, @@init_connect AS init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@license AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names, @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout, @@performance_schema AS performance_schema, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@transaction_isolation AS transaction_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout

```
2023-08-23T17:45:17.287781Z    27 Query SET character_set_results = NULL

2023-08-23T17:45:17.288150Z    27 Query SET autocommit=1

2023-08-23T17:45:17.288631Z    27 Query SET autocommit=0

2023-08-23T17:45:17.289342Z    26 Query DELETE FROM ORDINE  WHERE  ID_ordine=125

2023-08-23T17:45:17.290633Z    27 Query SELECT * FROM CARRELLO  WHERE    deleted='N'AND ID_user=31 AND Stato_c='Aperto'

2023-08-23T17:45:17.293113Z    27 Query DELETE FROM CARRELLO  WHERE  ID_carrello=145

2023-08-23T17:45:17.294688Z    27 Query UPDATE Carrello  SET Stato_c = 'Aperto' WHERE  ID_carrello=141 AND Stato_c= 'Chiuso'

2023-08-23T17:45:17.295915Z    27 Query SELECT * FROM CARRELLO  WHERE    deleted='N'AND ID_user=31 AND Stato_c='Aperto'

2023-08-23T17:45:17.297347Z    27 Query SELECT * FROM CartItem JOIN PRODOTTO ON ID_amulet=ID_amuleto  WHERE    CartItem.deleted='N'AND ID_car=141 ORDER BY PRODOTTO.Nome

2023-08-23T17:45:17.299415Z    27 Query SELECT Quantità_disp FROM PRODOTTO  WHERE    Deleted=0 AND Blocked=0 AND ID_amuleto=11 AND Quantità_disp>=3

2023-08-23T17:45:17.300294Z    27 Query commit
```

2023-08-23T17:45:17.310637Z    28 Connect   root@localhost on amuletshop using TCP/IP
2023-08-23T17:45:17.311448Z    28 Query /* mysql-connector-j-8.0.32 (Revision: fa4912a849140828e48162a2c396c8df0091bed7) */SELECT  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment, @@character_set_client AS character_set_client, @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection, @@character_set_results AS character_set_results, @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@collation_server AS collation_server, @@collation_connection AS collation_connection, @@init_connect AS init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@license AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names, @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout, @@performance_schema AS performance_schema, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@transaction_isolation AS transaction_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout

```
2023-08-23T17:45:17.312215Z    28 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
2023-08-23T17:45:17.312635Z    28 Query SET autocommit=1
2023-08-23T17:45:17.313138Z    28 Query SET autocommit=0
2023-08-23T17:45:17.313850Z    26 Query SELECT *    FROM ORDINE  WHERE    ID_ordine = 125
2023-08-23T17:45:17.314639Z    28 Query commit
2023-08-23T17:45:17.315071Z    28 Query rollback
2023-08-23T17:45:17.315327Z    28 Quit
```

In MySQL WorkBench the order with ID_ordine = 125 continue to be there. So the delete didn't effectly work even if it is in the log.

My questions are:
**Why in the log the delete has query identificator=26 and not 27** considered that it should be executed inside the delete of the cart (see in the top of the catch of NotAvailableProductEception)?

**Why the record of the table ORDINE isn't actually deleted?**

I know that there are several security problem such as storing the credit card information into the database and store the UserID in the cookie directly, but the website won't be published, it's just for an exam where the professor told us to don't manage the security (he just mind the software engineering).

If you see that I'm doing something wrong please let me know, **thank you in advance**.

Comment: order is a reserved word, so you should get an error,

Comment: if you mean in the function "public Order setCanceledStatus (Order order)", in my real program instead of SELECT * FROM ORDER there is SELECT * FROM ORDINE and instead of UPDATE ORDER there is UPDATE ORDINE. In this question (in stackoverflow) I translate the names in English from my language with the aim of simplifying readability for everyone. Anyway thank you for the answer

Comment: @nbk can you see something else that could give me this problem? client side the page is correctly redirected into the cart.jsp page and all the others entity are correctly updated with the wanted values (for example the cart is correctly deleted thanks to the function cartDAO.delete(Opencart) that you can find inside the catch under the function that cancel the order). So this make me think that there haven't been a rollback. I even try to substitute the function setCanceledStatus (order) with a function that perform a DELETE. But even in this case everything is correctly done except this

Comment: if you don't get an exception you are probably connected to the wrong server. easy would be tpo check with wiresharl if you are connected to the right server or enable general log and see if the update command reaches the server

Comment: But I'm a little bit confused, if there is no connection then i shouldn't be able to update or read anything in the database? instead when i run the program everything work fine (i can see the change of the status of the database from MySQL WorkBench) except for that function

Comment: look the command isnit the issue, when you run it and it throws no error , so the driver accepoted the query. you can check with affected rows how many where updated. But if none your where clause didn't find a match, if  one was updated you are not connected to the correct server. both we can not check for you.

Comment: I checked the general log: here everything seems fine. There is the delete (i substituted the function setCanceledStatus (Order order) with a function that perform the delete of that order). But anyway the status of the order is pending when i go to check it in MySQL WorkBench.

Comment: i thought you were uodating the column, not delete it, a status only change when you upodate it directly or use a trigger. if all commands you send are appearing in the general log, all should be fine, I think you missed some information

Comment: Yes I was doing it, I just change the function setCanceledStatus  with a function that perform the delete to see if it was a function problem. Tomorrow I will try again with the function  that I shared in this question and share the logs in this post. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: @nbk as you can see I edit the question and i reported the new function and the log. Thank you in advance

Comment: so oyur log show that the first had an error and the last also why it runs a ROLLBACK, so your queries abouve don't work kucky for you that nothing was deleted take the 1 log start a transaction and see where  it fails, all the comands are valid but the could b triggers or contraints that could lead to the rollback.

Comment: So I think the first query failed because there is an exception of NotAvaibleProductException so it is correct that there is a ROLLBACK (in fact inside the catch of NotAvaibleProductException i did a rollback). The problem is the last query, that rollback is not wanted.

Comment: But the DELETE is in the second query (number 27 in the log), not in the last query(number 28). So i think the DELETE shouldn't be affected by ROLLBACK, am I wrong? @nbk

Comment: the chnages from the second Log show no error so should be visible in the database

Comment: But the delete haven't been performed unfortunately. There aren't any foreign keys from other tables that are linked with the table ORDINE ( just the table ORDINE have foreign keys linked with other tables), so i think the problem shouldn't be constraints.

Comment: Constraints would through an error you should check in workbench  if you have triggers

Comment: I did the command SHOW TRIGGERS and no triggers were found @nbk

Comment: last input from me,  see ig the error log shows any anomalies, i can not  reproduce the error you get

Comment: If you mean the rollback immediately after the commit in the last query I probably found the motivation at this link [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/290747/what-could-be-the-reason-for-running-rollback-after-a-commit)

Comment: A maybe important thing that i noticed is that the query DELETE in the second transaction is owned by the first transaction (the number is 26 not 27). And the transaction number 26 never do a commit after the DELETE. Is maybe this one the motivation? @nbk

Comment: yes , your log shows that you flow control isn't finalized, you should rethink your approach and eliminate the rollbacks, if possible